# I cannot get JavaFX GraphicsContext strokeText() to display monospaced fonts right

Tags: javafx, canvas, fonts, monospace, graphicscontext

**Question:** I would like for the GraphicContext object to stroke the text in a monospaced font. How can this be achieved?

**Problem:** I am using JavaFX. I have a Canvas object and a GrahpicsContext object. I want to use GraphicsContext's strokeText() method to draw text on the canvas. Before I call strokeText(), I use GraphicsContext object's setFont() to set the font to a monospaced font. It is important that all the characters in the string that I want to draw on the canvas have the same width.
I have tried drawing the text on the canvas with fonts Courier, Courier New and Monospace. I understood that these fonts are supposed to be monospaced. I have imported javafx.scene.text.Font.

However, when I check the text drawn on the canvas, I see this every time:
[Screenshot of the left corner of my canvas object.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aN9Uj.png)

To test the fonts I made the GraphicsContext object stoke 5 times characters '_', 'a', 'i', and 'W' each on their own row. The characters are not of equal size and the lines are of different length. Also, I don't see any change in the font.

Here is the code I use for creating the canvas, drawer and stroking the text:

```
Canvas canvas = new Canvas(800,200);
GraphicsContext drawer = canvas.getGraphicsContext2D();
drawer.setFill(Color.BLACK);
drawer.setFont(new Font("Monospaced",15));

drawer.strokeText("_____", 5, 5);
drawer.strokeText("aaaaa", 5, 25);
drawer.strokeText("iiiii", 5, 45);
drawer.strokeText("WWWWW", 5, 65);
```

I searched for information about monospaced fonts in java, tried importing java.awt.Fonts and looked through the javadoc of GraphicsContext but nothing seemed to help me with this problem.

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`new Font(String name, double size)`
creates a font based on the **full name** of the font and the **font size**.
`Font.font(String family, double size)` creates a font based on the **font family name** and the **font size**.

In your case the family name is `"Monospaced" (java.awt.Font.MONOSPACED)`,
the full name is `"Monospaced Regular"`, and the file name on my Windows platform
is `C:\Windows\Fonts\cour.ttf (Courier New)`.

I prefer

```
drawer.setFont(Font.font("Monospaced", 15));
```

but

```
drawer.setFont(new Font("Monospaced Regular", 15));
```

and

```
drawer.setFont(Font.loadFont(Files.newInputStream(Paths.get("C:/Windows/Fonts/cour.ttf")), 15));
```

works too.

Answer (score 0):

I will answer my own question here since I found a way to fix this problem. I am not aware what causes this problem, so answers are still more than welcome. However, this seemed to be the cure:

```
drawer.setFont(Font.font(java.awt.Font.MONOSPACED,15));
```

Thank you very much!